# Java: Multiple Data Resources inside the same servlet

Tags: java, servlets

"javax.naming.Context" is commonly used inside Java EE development. It's quite convenient to use it to establish dynamical database connection by calling its lookup function with given names of resources inside context.xml. The sample code is shown as following where "db_name" is the name you used to identify the database resource.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(); 
DataSource ds = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/db_name");
```

My concern is what are the differences between lookup resources by using the same context and lookup resources by using different contexts. And which approach makes more sense or suitable? Suppose all database resources are defined inside the same context.xml file. For example:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(); 
DataSource ds1 = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/db_name_ds1");
DataSource ds2 = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/db_name_ds2");
```

and

```
Context ctx_ds1 = new InitialContext(); 
Context ctx_ds2 = new InitialContext(); 
DataSource ds1 = ctx_ds1.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/db_name_ds1");
DataSource ds2 = ctx_ds2.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/db_name_ds2");
```

Thank you for your sharing.

Comment: In this case, I think they are equivalent. The `Context#lookup(String)` method can return any object (depending on the factory used to handle the requested resource), even another context.

Comment: Thanks again, SD. I'm not sure about the "even another context" you mentioned, can you further elaborate a bit about it?

Comment: A context can contain another context. So you could use the `lookup()` method to return a sub context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no difference except you created an unnecessary extra java object. however, if the jndi server was remote, you would have created two different network connections and iverhead of managing them - definetly not what one should do.

Comment: Dear AS, thank you for your suggestion, I got it. To me, I also thought that one connection is good enough while I face some exceptions so that I want to isolate the root cause.